# React-admin ReferenceInput pulling document id instead source field

Tags: react-admin, react-final-form

Calling a ReferenceInput with an AutocompleteInput grabs the right document, and returns the "name" to the input but when you save it saves the document id to the source not the value of "name". Apparanetly React-admin does not allow anything but id to be saved natively, but the name is stored in the input until the document is saved. Is there any way to get the name from the input, and pass it to the format command maybe?

> Expected result: input saves the value of the name from the document

```
<ReferenceInput label="Name" source="name" reference="profiles" filterToQuery={searchText => ({ name: searchText })} >
        <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" source="name" resettable="true" shouldRenderSuggestions="true"  />
      </ReferenceInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct - the default property of the object `react-admin` uses inside choice inputs (Select / Autocomplete) is the `id`. To override this behaviour you only have to pass one more prop to the `<AutocompleteInput/>` which is the `optionValue` e.g.:

```
   <AutocompleteInput optionValue="name" ... />
```

And it should do exactly as you want it to.

Comment: setting optionValue to anything but id, causes the error "Associated reference no longer appears to be available." and the app freezes until reload. Looks like there are several issues reported about this on the projects github with no resolution i can find